# Doubt on a probability exercise from the book Ross 'A first Course in Probability'

Tags: probability, random-variables

I report the premises made by the book that lead to the resolution of the exercise:

It is customary to denote the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal
random variable by $\Phi(x)$. That is,

$$\Phi(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{x} e^{-y^2/2} dy $$

The values of $\Phi(x)$ for nonnegative $x$ are given in Table 5.1 (irrelevant to know the table for the purposes of the question). For negative values of $x$,
$\Phi(x)$ can be obtained from the relationship

Equation (4.1)

$$\Phi(−x) = 1 − \Phi(x), \ -\infty < x < \infty$$

The proof of Equation (4.1), which follows from the symmetry of the standard normal density, is left as an exercise. This equation states that if Z is a standard normal
random variable, then

$$P(Z≤−x) = P(Z > x), \  -\infty < x < \infty$$

Since $Z = (X − \mu)/\sigma$ is a standard normal random variable whenever $X$ is normally
distributed with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$, it follows that the distribution function of $X$
can be expressed as

$$F_x(a) = P(X \leq a) = P\left(\frac{X − \mu}{σ}\leq\frac{a − \mu}{\sigma}\right) = \Phi\left(\frac{a − \mu}{\sigma}\right)$$

Here is the exercise:

If X is a normal random variable with parameters $\mu = 3$ and $\sigma^2 = 9$, find  $P(2 <
X < 5)$.

$$P(2 < X < 5) = P\left(\frac{2 − 3}{3}<\frac{X − 3}{3}<\frac{5 − 3}{3}\right) $$ $$= p\left(-\frac{1}{3}<Z<\frac{2}{3}\right)$$ $$ = \Phi\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)- \Phi\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \qquad (1)$$ $$ = \Phi\left(\frac{2}{3}\right) - \left[1-\Phi\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\right] ≈ .3779$$

how do you justify the step $\qquad (1)$?

Comment: $P(Z < -1/3) + P(-1/3 < Z < 2/3) = P(Z  < 2/3).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $Z$ is a continuous random variable, we have $P(a<Z<b)=P(a<Z\le b)$ so I will focus on the right-hand side.

For any random variable $Z$,
$$P(a < Z \le b) = P(Z \le b) - P(Z \le a).$$
To show this, note that this is equivalent to $P(Z \le a) + P(a < Z \le b) = P(Z \le b)$, which follows from the following axiom: if $A$ and $B$ are **disjoint** events, then $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you made an error in transcribing the solution, there is a typo in step $(1)$. It should be

$$  \Phi\left(\frac23\right) - \Phi\left(-\frac13\right). $$

Notice that in the next step, the second term is replaced by
$$ 1 - \Phi\left(\frac13\right)$$
which we know (from Equation $4.1$) is equal to
$$ \Phi\left(-\frac13\right). $$

Comment: David K, initially it didn't work for me too, but then following the suggestion of angryavian you can see that

$$P(\frac{-1}{3}<Z≤\frac{2}{3}) = P(Z≤\frac{2}{3})- P(Z≤-\frac{1}{3})$$ $$= (\frac{2}{3}) - (-\frac{1}{3}) $$ $$= (\frac{2}{3}) - [1-(\frac{1}{3})]\qquad (1)$$

the (1) we get it  from Equation 4.1 indeed if $Φ(−)=1−Φ(), −∞<<∞$ we have that $ (-\frac{1}{3})$ becomes $ [1-(\frac{1}{3})]$